# Failed binder transaction when launching new Activity

Tags: android

I have a button on an Activity which launches another Activity.  When I click it, I get the error at the bottom of this thread.

A quick Google search lead me to a thread on this topic.  The thread talks about massive image resources.  Indeed, on this screen, I have a list where each row contains an image.  That image is retrieved by a web service and shown in the list.  I decided to cut off the code that does this so the images wouldn't be a problem.  The error still occurred.  Now I'm not sure what to do.  I am not using any of these ImageViews or calling web services for images.  I'm simply setting the image resource to null.

ActivityFilter is the Activity I'm attempting to launch.  ActivitySettings is the parent of the parent of this Activity.

Any ideas?

```
02-28 15:43:58.694: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.myapp.app/.activity.ActivityFilter (has extras) }
02-28 15:43:58.774: E/JavaBinder(58): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
02-28 15:44:03.765: W/ResourceType(58): Skipping entry 0x7f040004 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
02-28 15:44:03.765: W/ResourceType(58): Skipping entry 0x7f040003 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
02-28 15:44:08.726: W/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-28 15:44:08.783: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{451f4ea0 com.myapp.app/.activity.ActivityFilter}
02-28 15:44:11.687: W/WindowManager(58): Key dispatching timed out sending to <null>: no window ready for key dispatch
02-28 15:44:11.687: W/WindowManager(58): Previous dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to Window{451abdd0 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.activity.ActivitySettings paused=false} @ 1362086851467 lw=Window{451abdd0 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.activity.ActivityAccountSettings paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@44ebb660 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{451abdd0 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.activity.ActivitySettings paused=false}}}
02-28 15:44:11.687: W/WindowManager(58): Current dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=0 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to null @ 1362087851693 lw=null lb=null fin=true gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=null}}
```

Comment: Are you implementing Parcelable in any class in your app?

Comment: Yes, and I'm passing some data through the Intent that is Parcelable.  I've never had a problem with this before, though.

Comment: It seems as though one of my arrays of Parcelables is simply, too big.  No idea what I should do.  I need that data :\

Comment: My Parcelable had two member variables (ints) which I was no longer using.  I removed them so they weren't being instantiated a billion times, and now my problem is "gone."  I mean, the problem is still possible, but isn't happening with my current workflow.

Comment: Interesting that `int`s were one problem. Congrats on finding a solution!

Comment: Well, there are 2 in each instance of the object, and there were almost 5000 objects in the array :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Parcelable was using a lot of memory.

My Parcelable had two member variables (ints) which I was no longer using. I removed them so they weren't being instantiated a billion times, and now my problem is "gone." I mean, the problem is still possible, but isn't happening with my current workflow.